# Vim, uncomment block of python code starting with # + space. The v-block way

Tags: python, vim

It is common to comment the block of python with with # following with space. 
So using the v-block mode with `ctrl+v`, how to delete the first 2 character? Using `x` will leave a spacebar at the head of line, which messes up the indentation.

```
# class Memoize:
#     def __init__(self, func):
#         self.func = func
#         self.cache = {}
#     def __call__(self, arg):
#         if arg not in self.cache:
#             self.cache[arg] = self.func(arg)
#         return self.cache[arg]
```

I know using substitute (s) can do the job, but I find that to be quite slow.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Go to the beginning of the first line, where you want to delete the first 2 chars from.
2. Press `Ctrl+v`. Enter the Visual block mode.
3. Use the arrow keys to select multiple chars.
4. In your case, press `right arrow key` once. This will select `#` and `space`.
5. Press `down arrow key` to select the multiple lines.
6. Press `x` to delete them all.

Below are the images doing the same:

#### *Bring the cursor to beginning of the first line:*

[image]

#### *Enter the visual block mode and follow Steps #3 and #4:*

[image]

#### *Press `x` and save your file:*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### ctrl-v

- move your cursor on the `#` of the `class` line, press `ctrl-v`
- press `jjjjj..l` till the suitable line or `Gl` if the last commented line is the end of the file.
- press `x`

### :s

- select (`v` or `ctrl-v`) the lines
- press `:s/^# //` then enter.